# PHP AltoRouter Pass a route completely to a controller

Tags: php, altorouter

With AltoRouter, I need to pass any request starting with `/customer` to some `path/to/CustomerController.php` file and there then do all my specific matches.

In `CustomerController.php` I would have all my methods matched, ie:

```
public static function Transfer(){... this will be invoked from /customer/transfer...
public static function Register(){... this will be invoked from /customer/register...
```

in Laravel you can do this with:

```
Route::controller("customer", 'CustomerController');
```

I need exactly the same thing but with AltoRouter. I can't find any way to do it

http://altorouter.com/

(I just don't want to have one only routes file handling all the controllers method on my site but have each controller handle all it's specific route's methods)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code snippet in the documentation maybe it helps you:

```
// map users details page using controller#action string
$router->map( 'GET', '/users/[i:id]/', 'UserController#showDetails' );
```

If that doesn't help you could check out my router [Sail](https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Sail). I build it to allow programmers a more object oriented way to build their APIs.

**Edit**

Here is an example how you can solve this with Sail.

```
use Sail\Sail;
use Sail\Tree;
use Sail\Exceptions\NoSuchRouteException;
use Sail\Exceptions\NoMiddlewareException;
use Sail\Exceptions\NoCallableException;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$sail = new Sail();

class UserController extends Tree {

    public function build () {
        $this->get('transfer', function($request, $response) {
            self::transfer($request, $response);
        });

        $this->get('register', function($request, $response) {
            self::register($request, $response);
        });
    }

    public static function transfer(&$request, &$response) {
        //do your stuff
    }

    public static function register(&$request, &$response) {
        //do your stuff
    }
}

$sail->tree('customer', new UserController());

try {
    $sail->run();
} catch (NoSuchRouteException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (NoMiddlewareException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (NoCallableException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't works...And you are colling a specific method under the UserController(showdetails) in that route map example....remember I want a map to send All traffic starting with /users to the controller. PS: You didn't provide an example to do it with your Sail router either.

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez I added an example to my post! An other way to solve your problem would be to write your own mapping function that reads all methods form UserController and adds them this way: $router->map( 'GET', '/consumer/functionName', 'UserController#functionName' );

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez check out this method http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-class-methods.php